# Removing a class from parent when clicking anything inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I couldn't find the exact scenario am looking for. 
I am trying to toggle off a class out of a parent div in a way alternative to the closing button. Just to give you a clear idea, I'm posting the whole code.

```
    $('.team__list li').on('click', function() {
        $('.team__list li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        console.log('hi');
    }); 

    $('.team__list li .close-button').click(function(event) {
        $(this).closest('.team__list li').removeClass('active');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('.active *').on('click',function(event) {
        console.log('hi');
        $(this).closest('.team__list li').removeClass('active');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

The first block triggers the active class when the element is clicked and removes it from siblings, the second, correctly removes the class upon closing the button. However, I can't get the third block to fire at all.

It should be noted (not sure if it matters) that upon receiving the class active, a child element (with children itself) gets absolutely positioned on top of the active element.

Edit:

```
$('.team__list li').not('.active').on('click', function(event) {
        $('.team__list li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        console.log('open');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });



    $('.team__list li .close-button').click(function(event) {
        $(this).closest('.team__list li').removeClass('active');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(".team__list").on('click', ".active *", function(event) {
        console.log('close');
        $(this).closest('.team__list li').removeClass('active');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding and removing `class` during the run time, you have to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind your events. Because events registered during page load are not applicable to the elements which is qualified for that event during run time.

```
$(".team__list").on('click', ".active *", function(event) {
   //your code goes here.
```

Comment: This is helpful! isolated, the event fires however the whole code still doesnt toggle as I need it to. I have edited the question reflect the current code.

Comment: @Leoland I cannot understand what you are saying. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Of course. 
So there is a grid of team members. When clicking on one of them they become '.active' and their children (the modal with full info about that member) become visible and are absolutely positioned on top of the team member.

the problem seems to be that if I don't stop propagation on the opening click. it auto-closes. but if I do stop it. i can never fire the closing script.

Comment: @Leoland Try to add `if($(e.target).is('.team__list li')) { return false; }` as a first line of close handler.

Comment: Still nothing. Experimenting with the idea of a boolean each click toggles. (which should be covered by the active class) but the propagation issue seems to be there regardless.

Comment: @Leoland Can you create a simple reproducible demo in jsfiddle.net ? So that it would be easy for me to avail a fix for you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jpczk822/  this seems to work though... could i post a link to a staging environment?

Comment: @Leoland Yes please.

Comment: I got it, Thank you so much. you got me 99% of the way there you are a GOLDEN god. As far as the JS go your answer was perfect. Eventualy i got it to work by using a more specific selector:

$(".team__list .teammate__full").on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('close');
  $(this).closest('.team__list li').removeClass('active');
  event.stopPropagation();
});

but for anyone else your answer was great.

Comment: @Leoland Glad to help! :) Try to press the tick mark present inside this answer, if you think that this answer has helped you. And that is not a compulsion. :)

Comment: How can i message you the link directly. I am would rather not leave it here permanently, That is if you are curious why the * selector wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: @Leoland You can message that link here if it is not sensitive. And here in india it is 4 am. Gonna take a nap now. Will check it and I will ping back later. :)